# Create delegate dynamically from Type name

Tags: c#, generics

i would like to create a generic delegate but i only know the type while the execution.

here is the delegate that i want to create :

```
public delegate void MyDel<T>(T t,string msg);
```

and here is the method in which i want to instantiate and use the delegate

```
Type typeSet = set.GetType();
MethodInfo method = typeSet.GetMethod("Add");    
Delegate test = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDel<typeSet>, method);
```

where typeSet is unknow for me at the compilation.
and unfortunately, the method that i want to call is not static.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need to create the specific delegate type using [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx):

```
Type template = typeof(MyDel<>);
Type specific = template.MakeGenericType(typeSet);
Delegate test = Delegate.CreateDelegate(specific, method);
```

I *think* that's what you're after...

Comment: thanks for your response, how can i call the delegate now ?              something like this :                                                      if (test != null)
{
    MyDel<> myDel = (MyDel<>)test;
    myDel("blabla");
}

Comment: @user1005016: You can use `Delegate.InvokeDynamic` if you've got the arguments and can be reasonably sure they're okay, but you don't know the compile-time type of the delegate.

Comment: I want to call the "add" method on Entity framework DbSet entities

public delegate void DelegateAddObject<T>(T t,DbSet entity);
Type contextType = (context as Object).GetType();
var set = (contextType.GetProperty(entitySetName)).GetValue(context, null);
Type typeSet = set.GetType();
MethodInfo method = typeSet.GetMethod("Add");

Type template = typeof(DelegateAddObject<>);
Type specific = template.MakeGenericType(typeSet);
Delegate test = Delegate.CreateDelegate(specific, method);

Where context is my dataContext.
But  i get the following error : **Error binding to target method**

Comment: @user1005016: It looks like you're using the wrong type for the generic method type argument - I'd thought `typeSet` was the *parameter* type for the method - that's what you want as the `T` of `DelegateAddObject<T>`, right?

Comment: I don't really know, i just want to call the add method on DbSet object. Here, T is the type of the object i want to add but as it's not a static method, i must also give the type to my delegate ?? i'm lost...