# Invoke a method using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, json.net, ros

I am trying to connect to and subscribe to Topics on ROSbridge using the ros-sharp project. It works fine if i specify the Type of message upon subscribing as per the code example in the Test Client:

```
rosSocket = new RosSocket(new RosBridgeClient.Protocols.WebSocketNetProtocol(uri), RosSocket.SerializerEnum.Newtonsoft_JSON);
string subscription_id = rosSocket.Subscribe<JointState>("/joint_states", SubscriptionHandler);
```

Where this is the Subscribe method:

```
public string Subscribe<T>(string topic, SubscriptionHandler<T> subscriptionHandler, int throttle_rate = 0, int queue_length = 1, int fragment_size = int.MaxValue, string compression = "none") where T : Message
{
string id;
lock (SubscriberLock)
{
id = GetUnusedCounterID(Subscribers, topic);
Subscription subscription;
Subscribers.Add(id, new Subscriber<T>(id, topic, subscriptionHandler, out subscription, throttle_rate, queue_length, fragment_size, compression));
Send(subscription);
}
return id;
}
```

the Delegate type is:

```
namespace RosSharp.RosBridgeClient
{
public delegate void SubscriptionHandler<T>(T t) where T : Message;
```

And the Subscription Handler is as follows:

```
private static void SubscriptionHandler(object message)
{
    string msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((Message)message, Formatting.None);
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

however I wish to be able to specify the topic and message type by string and find that type and call the subscribe method.

I know I can do it with an exhaustive Switch e.g.:

```
public static string SubscribeSwitch(string type, string topic) 
{
switch (type)
{
case "sensor_msgs/JointState":
    return rosSocket.Subscribe<JointState>(topic, SubscriptionHandler);
    break;
case "actionlib_msgs/GoalID":
    return rosSocket.Subscribe<GoalID>(topic, SubscriptionHandler);
    break;
}
return "";
}
```

But this will get pretty long and unmanageable especially if i add new Message types for different robots. I have therefore spent some time trying to use reflection to get the type to invoke the Subscribe call, but I seem to be falling over when trying to pass in the Subscription handler which has a non generic delegate type. Has anyone done similar, or provide an example of how to do this - many thanks. The following code for exmaple falls over at var subscribe: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.Message'.

```
Type msgType = Type.GetType("RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.MessageTypes.Sensor.JointState,RosBridgeClient");

var mi = typeof(RosSocket).GetMethod("Subscribe");

Type[] aparams = new Type[1];
aparams[0] = msgType;
var fooRef = mi.MakeGenericMethod(aparams);

object[] test2 = new object[1];
test2[0] = msgType;

object[] test = new object[6];
test[0] = "/joint_states";

// get subscribe method info
var subscribe = typeof(RosSocketConsole).GetMethod(nameof(SubscriptionHandler), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, test2);

test[1] = subscribe;
test[2] = 0;
test[3] = 1;
test[4] = int.MaxValue;
test[5] = "none";
string subscription_id = (string)fooRef.Invoke(rosSocket, test);
```

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Are you sure the shown code throws the `InvalidCastException`? You'll get `System.RuntimeType` when you accidentally call `GetType()` on a `Type` instance (e.g. `typeof(string).GetType()`). But I can't see that being done with `msgType` in your code.

Comment: Wait what are you even doing in the `var subscribe = ...` line? That line makes no sense to me. You have the use the generic method you created (like you are doing in the last line). Please get rid of all the obsolete stuff from your example code. Just show a minimal, failing example.

Comment: A basic improvement would be `var subscribe = type switch { "sensor_msgs/JointState" => rosSocket.Subscribe<JointState>, "actionlib_msgs/GoalID" => rosSocket.Subscribe<GoalID>, _ => "" }; return subscribe(topic, SubscriptionHandler);`. Or other straightforward ways to extract duplicate code.

Comment: the issue with the switch approach is that there are hundreds of Message types and I preferably don't want to have to maintain a switch to cater for all of them, especially as new message types can be added.

Comment: The main bit I'm struggling on is how to specify the second parameter for the Subscription Handler:

`Type msgType = Type.GetType("RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.MessageTypes.Sensor.JointState,RosBridgeClient");
var mi = typeof(RosSocket).GetMethod("Subscribe");

var fooRef = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { msgType });
string subscription_id = (string)fooRef.Invoke(rosSocket, new object[] { "/joint_states", ????, 0, 1, int.MaxValue, "none" });`

Comment: You mean how to pass SubscriptionHandler to the reflective invocation?

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: @oddball you need to use the delegate type, that of the second parameter as declared in the signature of `rosSocket.Subscribe<T>`, whatever that is. It could be something like `Action<object>` but I don't know because I can't see it in the question.

Comment: Have added the rosSocket Subscribe methos in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this seems to be the solution - the type of the Delegate is determined, and the runtime type assigned to it using MakeGenericType before Creating the delegate:

```
rosSocket = new RosSocket(new RosBridgeClient.Protocols.WebSocketNetProtocol(uri), RosSocket.SerializerEnum.Newtonsoft_JSON);

Type msgType = Type.GetType("RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.MessageTypes.Sensor.JointState,RosBridgeClient");
var mi = typeof(RosSocket).GetMethod("Subscribe");

var di = typeof(RosSocketConsole).GetMethod(nameof(SubscriptionHandler), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

Type template = typeof(SubscriptionHandler<>);
Type specific = template.MakeGenericType(msgType);
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(specific, di);

var fooRef = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { msgType });
string subscription_id = (string)fooRef.Invoke(rosSocket, new object[] { "/joint_states", del, 0, 1, int.MaxValue, "none" });
```

This provided the solution in relation to creating the delegate and assigning the type at runtime:

[Create delegate dynamically from Type name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835013/create-delegate-dynamically-from-type-name)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

So this solves creating the delegate and passing into the reflective invocation, but the Delegate type is again hard coded - I want it to be the same as msgType (but you can't use msgType as the CreateDelegate type, as you get 'msgType' is a variable but is used like a type):

```
Type msgType = Type.GetType("RosSharp.RosBridgeClient.MessageTypes.Sensor.JointState,RosBridgeClient");
var mi = typeof(RosSocket).GetMethod("Subscribe");

var di = typeof(RosSocketConsole).GetMethod(nameof(SubscriptionHandler), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RosBridgeClient.SubscriptionHandler<JointState>), di);

var fooRef = mi.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { msgType });
string subscription_id = (string)fooRef.Invoke(rosSocket, new object[] { "/joint_states", del, 0, 1, int.MaxValue, "none" });
```